# Uncaught TypeError: AWS.TranscribeService is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, amazon-cognito, speech-to-text, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to access AWS Transcribe API via JavaScript SDK on my web page for implement a sample Text to Speech web application. I had referred the documentation in AWS websites, include generating the `CognitoIdentityCredentials`.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.653.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;

    AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
        access_key_id: 'xxxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxx',
        region: 'us-east-2'
    });

    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-2:xx-xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx',
    });

    console.log(AWS);

    debugger;
    var transcribeservice = new AWS.TranscribeService();
</script>
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: `TranscribeService` does not support browser side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create your own build of the AWS SDK for JavaScript is to use the SDK builder web application at https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js. Use the SDK builder to specify services, and their API versions, to include in your build.

Choose **Select all services** or choose **Select default services** as a starting point from which you can add or remove services. Choose **Development** for more readable code or choose **Minified** to create a minified build to deploy. After you choose the services and versions to include, choose **Build** to build and download your custom SDK.